# Execute 'where' command in cmd with PowerShell Studio

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I've just tried to exec this command, and works, but I want to know if there is a way to cut the path printed. This is the [doc page](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html) I read, an this is what it prints

```
"C:\Users\user\Downloads\NSClient v67.msi"
```

I want only the path, without the filename, something like `"C:\Users\bryanar\Downloads\"` so I can `cd` to that path and exec the .msi

Any ideas?

Comment: Look up `for`.  Something like `for /f %%a in ('where') do echo "%%~dpa"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
14:10:31.27  C:\src
>FOR %A IN ("C:\Users\user\Downloads\NSClient v67.msi") DO (ECHO "%~dpA")

14:10:33.30  C:\src
>(ECHO "C:\Users\user\Downloads\" )
"C:\Users\user\Downloads\"
```

In a .bat file script, double the % character on the loop variable.

```
FOR %%A IN ("C:\Users\user\Downloads\NSClient v67.msi") DO (ECHO "%%~dpA")
```

Doing this in PowerShell is easy as well.

```
$thedir = (Get-ChildItem "$Env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\NSClient v67.msi").Directory.ToString()
$thedir = (Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\user\Downloads\NSClient v67.msi").Directory.ToString()
```

Comment: I cannot make it work, I'm using PowerShell Studio, and when I run this line `$filePath = Invoke-Expression -Command:'FOR %%A IN ('$rawPath') DO (ECHO "%%~dpA")'` I get the following error `ERROR: Invoke-Expression : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '"C:\Users\bryan\Downloads\NSClient v67 (1).msi"
ERROR: "C:\Users\bryan\Downloads\NSClient v67.msi") DO (ECHO "%%~dpA")'.`

Comment: @BryanArreola - This is not PowerShell. This runs in cmd.exe.

Comment: Yes, I know, I've run it in cmd.exe and works perfectly. In PowerShell Studio I use `Invoke-Expression` to run the command in cmd but I ran into those errors.